# How to set default values through DB in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.defaultValues = {
        Id: ko.observable(16),
        name: ko.observable("SUkhi"),        
    }; 
};

var model = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

How can set the default values 16 and 'Sukhi' from DB, by calling function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this depending on what you need.

example 1

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(16);
    self.name: ko.observable("SUkhi")
};

var model = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);

// this will create models with the default values
```

example 2 (my favorite)

```
 var ViewModel = function (ctor) {
    var self = this;
    var default: {
      id = 16
      name: "SUkhi"
    }
    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.name: ko.observable()

    /// if using pure JS
    if(!!ctor){ 
        for(var i in ctor){
           if(ctor.hasOwnProperty("i") && self.hasOwnProperty("i"){
               if(ko.isSubscribable(self[i])) { // check if it is observable
                   self[i](ctor[i])
               }
               else {
                   self[i] = ctor[i];
               }
           }
        }
    }
    // end pure JS

    /// if using jquery
    $.extend(self, ctor);
    // end jquery
};

var model = new ViewModel(); // or
var model = new ViewModel({ Id: 5, Name: "Whateva"})
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

written from memory, but its all there